# Shell enviroment variables in for loop CI/CD

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have trouble with using values in for loop, because I know - shell enviroment file is working but in for loop nothing happens.

shell enviroment file

```
export CONFIGS="test1 test2 test3"
export APP_NAMES="app1 app2 app3"
```

gitlab ci/cd job script (this for loop showing mi values from configs 3 times, but I want one value from two variables in echo)

```
    - |
      for APP_NAME in $APP_NAMES
        do
          for CONFIG in $CONFIGS
            do
              echo $CONFIG
          done
        done
```

In job i only see this and job thinks is great and nothing happens next

**$ for CONFIG in $CONFIGS # collapsed multi-line command
**
Do you have any ideas?

I try testing in bash and is don't working properly. I expect working for loop

Comment: did you ```source your_env_file.sh``` ?

Comment: yes, 
.common:
  interruptible: true
  before_script:
    - source variables/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.env

Comment: try to source the env file within the script block.

Comment: dont work, i try to change to script block and in job i see same text with collapsed multi-line command

Comment: i fix this adding source to jobs without common and for using two variables in for loop, I use for ((i=0; i<${#CONFIGS[@]}; i++)); do and ${CONFIGS[$i]} and ${APP_NAMES[$i]}

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your GitLab CI/CD job script will traverse over the contents of the **$APP_NAMES** and **$CONFIGS** variables concurrently. Your nested for loop's present approach, but, is flawed. For each loop, two distinct variables must be used. Try this:

---

```
- |
  for APP_NAME in $APP_NAMES
  do
    for CONFIG in $CONFIGS
    do
      echo "$APP_NAME - $CONFIG"
    done
  done
```

---